# Rails Routing Admin Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this AdminController

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_admin?

  def dashboard

  end

  def is_admin?
    redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :alert => "You are not an admin!" } if !current_user.admin?
  end

end
```

and this other controller that inherits from the above:

```
class Admin::CompetitionEntriesController < Admin::AdminController
  before_action :set_competition_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
....
end
```

My route file is:

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'competition_entries#index'

  devise_for :users
  resources :competition_entries

  namespace :admin do
    root 'admin#dashboard'
    resources :competition_entries
  end

....
..
.
end
```

Now why am I getting this error when I am trying to reach '`http://localhost:3000/admin`'

```
Missing template admin/admin/dashboard...
```

I am getting this extra admin? Why? I don't want to use scopes I want to use namespaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes do not affect default search paths for templates. If your controller class is named `Foo::BarController`, Rails will look for the templates in app/views/foo/bar/ unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: would you suggest another name for 'Admin::AdminController' ?

Comment: Since ```Admin::Admin``` looks kinda weird to me, I'd probably use something like ```Admin::BaseController```

Comment: `Admin::DashboardController#index` and that inherits from `Admin::BaseController` would be the thing that i do. regardless, in terms of the routing namespace, it directly translates in a module namespace in ruby!